# Possible compiler bug in MSVC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-bug

I believe I've found a compiler bug in MSVC++ (present up to VS 2013). I want to check that it is indeed a bug before I report it.

The following code:

```
#include <map>

using std::map;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef T StoredType;
};

template <typename T>
map<typename T::StoredType, int> foo()
{
    map<typename T::StoredType, int> ret;
    return ret;
}  

template<>
map<char, int> foo<A<char>>()
{
    map<char, int> ret;
    return ret;
} // Error on this line

int main(int, char**)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Produces a compile error:

```
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\proj\proj\source1.cpp(24): error C2785: 'std::map<T::StoredType,int> foo(void)' and 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> foo(void)' have different return types
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=char,
1>              _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          d:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\proj\proj\source1.cpp(13) : see declaration of 'foo'
1>          d:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\proj\proj\source1.cpp(20) : see declaration of 'foo'
1>d:\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\proj\proj\source1.cpp(24): error C2912: explicit specialization; 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> foo<A<T>>(void)' is not a specialization of a function template
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=char,
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              T=char
1>          ]
```

However, it looks OK to me, and compiles fine on ideone.com. Is it a bug? Should it compile cleanly?

Comment: Compiles fine on GCC 4.9.1

Comment: Out of curiosity, would it help if you made the primary template's body legal (i.e. changed the type of `ret` to `map<typename T::StoredType, int>`)?

Comment: @Angew same here, the code i wrong since `map<T, int>` is not `map<typename T::StoredType, int>`, even more curious if it compiles on GCC :D

Comment: Apologies - I was mucking about trying to find a minimal example and obviously didn't back up far enough. It still fails with a "correct" primary template body (as you'd expect - the template isn't instantiated, so it shouldn't ever be compiled). I'll edit the question.

Comment: It also appears I commented the wrong error line. Also fixed.

Comment: Well, at least VS2010 still gives me an error on the first line you said was faulty and it makes sense, but the weird thing is that T is deduced to `char` that is what makes me curious. Since it should have been A<char> as far as I understand.

Comment: All versions of VS, since VC4 or so, have a bug regarding two-phase template compilation (work done in the 2 phases is not correctly divided).

Comment: OK using Clang/LLVM (ver 3.5 C++14)

Comment: Ok, looks like a bug. I'll report it, and comment back here. FWIW, there is an even simpler failure case; instead of `A`, define `class B {public: typedef char StoredType; };`. Then the specialisation `map<char,int> foo<B>()` also fails.

Answer (score 1):

What is interesting that the same thing on a class specialization works fine:

```
#include <map>

using std::map;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef T StoredType;
};

template <typename T>
struct Z
{
    map<typename T::StoredType, int> foo()
    {
        map<T::StoredType, int> ret;
        return ret;
    }  // Error on this line
};

template<>
struct Z<A<char>>
{
    map<char, int> foo()
    {
        map<char, int> ret;
        return ret;
    }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    return 0;
}
```

If the map is defined in the template then it also seems fine:

```
#include <map>

using std::map;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef map<T, int> MapType;
};

template <typename T>
typename T::MapType foo()
{
    T::MapType ret;
    return ret;
}

template<>
map<char, int> foo<A<char>>()
{
    map<char, int> ret;
    return ret;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    return 0;
}
```

So the assumption about the bug seems to be possible.

Comment: Your answer would be easier to read if you just showed the parts that you’ve changed.